# Js2XML returned extra "item" tag when converting to XML

Tags: xml, typescript, xmlconvert, js2xml

I'm doing typescript project using [js2xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xml) package for convert json object to xml.

Below is the xml that I need as the **output**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Marks>
    <IndexNo>202104455</IndexNo>
    <IndexNo>20210488</IndexNo>
</Marks>
```

For that I create below interface in typescript.

```
export interface Subject {
    IndexNo: string[];
}
```

Then I assign values like below.

```
    let objSubject: Subject = {
      IndexNo: ["202104455", "20210488"]
    }

    var jsn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objSubject));
    console.log(jsn);
    var outputXML = new Js2Xml("Marks", jsn);
```

Above json is,

```
{ IndexNo: [ '202104455', '20210488' ] }
```

After executing, It returned below xml. The problem is extra "item" tag appear inside indexNo tag. What I want is above mentioned xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Marks>
  <IndexNo>
    <item>202104455</item>
    <item>20210488</item>
  </IndexNo>
</Marks>
```

How to fix above issue? Is there any other npm package for doing my task?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js), complex but working ;-)

```
import { js2xml } from 'xml-js';

const objSubject = {
  declaration: { attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'utf-8' } },
  elements: [
    {
      type: 'element',
      name: 'Marks',
      elements: [
        {
          type: 'element',
          name: 'IndexNo',
          elements: [{ type: 'text', text: '202104455' }],
        },
        {
          type: 'element',
          name: 'IndexNo',
          elements: [{ type: 'text', text: '20210488' }],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

var outputXML = js2xml(objSubject);

console.log(outputXML.toString());
```

Output:

```
<Marks><IndexNo>202104455</IndexNo><IndexNo>20210488</IndexNo></Marks>
```